# firebase.auth().signInWithPopup() not works with Chrome extension on Linux/Mac

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I am developing a chrome extension.I have used firebase google sign for authentication using firebase.auth().signInWithPopup() method.

It works well with Windows.But it do not works with Linux/Mac OS. A popup window appears for a while then it disappears.
Please suggest Solution.

Comment: Since it's working on Windows but not on Linux/Mac, this might be an issue with dev web server like localhost or 127.0.0.1. Try whitelisting these addresses as mentioned in this [github forum](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/issues/30)

Comment: @noogui
Thanks for responding.I have try whitelisting solution,but its not works for me.My extensions fails on Mac86X and on linux enviroment.

Comment: I just tested in Linux and signInWithPopup works as expected (v5.x). Make sure you are following the steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase_in_a_chrome_extension